# c# copy only integer value of variable

Tags: c#

Sorry for this noob question I forgot my lesson in c# so bear with me. I have this code

```
public class TestClass
{
     int indexcounter = 3;

     public int returnInteger()
     {
         int temporarystorage = indexcounter;
         indexcounter --;
         return temporarystorage;
     }
}
```

I first stored value of indexcounter to temporary storage which is 3. So i can return temporarystorage value which is 3. but it returns the value of 2. What's happening here

Comment: Define "not working" - because that code should work. What's your test code? (Note that a simpler implementation would just be `return indexcounter--`, which will return the value of `indexcounter` *before* it is decremented.)

Comment: "But this is not working" I guess this is supposed to mean: "not working as expected" so please tell us what you have expected. What you have there is a stereotypical example of call by reference and call by value

Comment: how are you using the value returned by returnInteger() method?

Comment: have a close look at [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)

Comment: Note that `--indexcounter` will return the value of `indexcounter` _after the decrement_ and `indexcounter--` will return the value of `indexcounter` _before the decrement_. As in, if `indexcounter` is 0, then `return --indexcounter` will return `-1`, whereas `return indexcounter--` will return `0`.

Comment: " I'm trying to return .. value of 3 **before** it gets decremented" So then your code works. I get a `3` as return value. Sounds like the case is closed...

Comment: sorry I rephrased my question

Comment: "but it returns the value of 2." NO, it does not. How did you test it? At the first call it returns a `3` and the second call it returns a `2` and the third call a `1` and so on...

Comment: Yes it will return the value of 2 on your 2nd call to the getter, and the value of 1 on your 3rd call. Each time you decrease the value of `indexcounter` by 1

Comment: @Newboy No that doesn't happen at all. Your example does not reproduce the problem you state you're seeing.

Comment: @Fabjan in my first call it returns 2.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you add the code that calls this class to show us how do you see that impossible result from just the code above

Comment: I [tested your code](https://rextester.com/MWWFTP49979) - please see the results.

Comment: As per @Steve's point above, we believe whatever the error is that you are getting isn't coming from the code that you've shown us, but is in the code that calls your function (which you've *not* included in your opening post).  Please include all the code - i;e. the but that calls `returnInteger()`. and then we will be able to point to exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code works just as you describe it should work.

BTW, the `returnInteger` method code can be simplified to `return indexcounter--;` - see [Decrement operator --](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#decrement-operator---) for details.

Here's a quick demonstration:

```
public class TestClass
{
    int indexcounter = 3;

    public int returnInteger()
    {
        int temporarystorage = indexcounter;
        indexcounter --;
        return temporarystorage;
    }

    // I've added that property so that we can inspect the value of indexcounter outside this class
    public int IndexCounter {get {return indexcounter;} }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new TestClass();

        Console.WriteLine(a.IndexCounter); // prints 3

        Console.WriteLine(a.returnInteger()); // prints 3

        Console.WriteLine(a.IndexCounter); // prints 2

        Console.WriteLine(a.returnInteger()); // prints 2

        Console.WriteLine(a.IndexCounter); // prints 1
    }
}
```

[You can see a live demo on rextetser.](https://rextester.com/PBXU34505)

Comment: Thanks Zohar maybe there is something i forgot in my code. :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not John but I see we had the same idea :-)